# How to apply background image to a xhtml file?

Tags: java, css, jsf, xhtml, background-image

I am working with javaee jsf pages. I have a page called main.xhtml. Here it is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"  >
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

        <a href="editinfo.xhtml">Edit Account</a>
        <a href="createaccount.xhtml">Create new account</a>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add a background image to the page. To do this i first tried in the body part:

```
 <h:body background-img="../images/background.jpg" >
```

but it does not work, there is no such attribure called background-img. Then i created a css file called styles.css.

```
.main
{
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
}
```

And edited the main.xhtml:

```
<h:body style="../src/java/css/styles.css" >
```

But this body declaration still gives an error saying that unexpected characters '.''.' found. I put those dots to go one folder up. Am i doing wrong? How can apply this image to the background of my page?

Thanks

Comment: Try this : http://bit.ly/127DcgA for adding the stylesheet.

Comment: @NickR if you noticed i already tried to do what i found on google

Comment: So you tried this : `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline *css*

```
<h:body style="background-image: url(../images/background.jpg)" >
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to inspect the same using a firefox extension like fireBug, then select the tag (with or without class) where you want the background image and just add a new rule to see which css it takes. Just take that CSS Rule, add in your stylesheet and apply a background image to it. Thats it.